# How to choose integer types for a new API written in Rust?

Tags: rust

What is the idiomatic way of choosing integer types in API written in Rust?

For example in C it's pretty common to use `int` even for function arguments which are expected to be positive. For sake of simplicity we use `int` type specifier even for arguments which can be fitted into a single byte.

Rust has a very strict type system, so all type conversions should be explicit. For example by making `Vec<T>::len()` return `usize`, the designers of the Rust standard library obligated us to insert tedious conversions to `isize` while performing non-trivial calculations (where negative values can appear).

So should I use specialized integer types when writing an API or is it worth just to stick with `isize`?

Update:

Will ask more specifically. I design a type called `NeuralNet` with the following instance constructor:

```
pub struct NeuralNet<F: traits::Float, A: Activator<F>> {
    phantom: marker::PhantomData<A>,
    inputs: isize,
    input_neurons: isize,
    folding_step: isize,
    layers: isize,
    coefs: vec::Vec<F>
}

impl<F: traits::Float, A: Activator<F>> NeuralNet<F, A> {
    pub fn new(inputs: isize, input_neurons: isize,
               folding_step: isize, layers: isize,
               coefs: &[F]) -> NeuralNet<F, A> {
    ...
}
```

Here `inputs` and `input_neurons` can be fitted into `u16`, `layers` can be fitted into `u8` and `folding_step`into `i8`. Should I use those type or just to stick with `isize` not to overcomplicate the constructor?

Comment: *obligated us to insert tedious conversions*  — this is just thinly veiled complaining and doesn't really suit asking an objective question. *in C it's pretty common to use `int`* — this is because C and C++ [doesn't handle unsigned numbers well](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html) (see the section "On Unsigned Integers"). This also helps explain the "tedious conversions" in Rust. Answers to this question are highly opinionated and boil down to "use the right type for your domain". We cannot tell you what your domain is.

Comment: What @Shepmaster said. Use whatever integer type fits. There's no "one rule" to determine what type you should use.

Comment: *tedious conversions* => Don't forget that you need to think over the edge cases that might break your code for each of these conversions. *That's* the tedious part, and Rust forces you to be careful about it.

Comment: The guidelines for the standard library are outlined in [#22240](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22240). That can form the basis of an answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 3.2 of The Rust Book states the following: ["So how do you know which type of integer to use? If you’re unsure, Rust’s defaults are generally good places to start: integer types default to i32. The primary situation in which you’d use isize or usize is when indexing some sort of collection."](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html).

Aside from this, you may also consider making your API generic over integer types, which would allow the user to decide which size to use.  This could be done with the num-traits crate's [PrimInt trait](https://github.com/rust-num/num-traits/blob/master/src/int.rs).